# Language changed but CLLocationManager didn't effected?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am using localization and cllocationManager

when change the language every thing working well just the country and city name come with the previous language not effected at all with the localization , the only way is to close the app and open it again to come with the new language !! 
Any solution to change the country and city without closing the app ?

localization code

```
static func setLanguage(lang:String) -> Void {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    UserDefaults.standard.set([lang], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    Bundle.setLanguage(lang)
}
```

CLLocationManager code

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    locValue = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")


    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        // Place details
        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placemarks?[0]

        if placeMark != nil{
            // City
            if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["State"] as? NSString {

                self.locCity = city as String
            }



            // Country
            if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Country"] as? NSString {

                self.locCountry = "\(country)," as String
            }

            self.countryLocation.text = "\(self.locCountry) \(self.locCity)"
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add an observer on `NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification` to detect any such change.

Something like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyClass.languageDidChange),
                                               name: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

And `languageDidChange` method will get called once something gets changed in `NSLocale`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i try it but same thing , the problem not in fire change of language the problem is the CLLocationManager didn't take any parameter of language  and it need to restart the app

Comment: @MOMMH have to you tried re-initialising the `CLLocationManager` ?

Comment: no but i don't know how to  re-initialising the CLLocationManager , any sample code or link please ?

Comment: reinitialising means you'll simply create a new object of `CLLocationManager`.  
Something like this: `self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()`

Comment: unfortunately sam thing after assign nil and reinitialising i almost made every thing but didn't effected , really thanks for your help